# X.509 certificate in trusted store for ubuntu - Powershell Microsoft graph

Tags: azure, powershell

Main goal
I am trying to find a way to add licenses to a user using ubuntu linux; either by powershell or any other programmable method. My last resort is to use selenium with python.

Actual problem
I am trying to use `Connect-MgGraph` cmdlet with a certificate for unattended scripts. The information on this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/app-only?tabs=azure-portal

I already have app registered with exchange and admin access. I also already have a cert. I used it before when connecting to exchange online powershell.

When I try to run: `Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $ApplicationId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateName $Certificate`

It Gives me an error: `certificate was not found or has expired.`

Here us what I tried:

I first tried using the certpath as a variable and then passing that - failed

```
$CertificateFilePath = "/home/tech/scripts/powershell_scripts/exchangecert/msexchange.pfx"
##other stuff
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $ApplicationId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateName $CertificateFilePath

### FAILED RESULT
Connect-MgGraph: /home/tech/scripts/powershell_scripts/exchangecert/msexchange.cer certificate was not found or has expired.
```

I tried using this bit of commands that I found from here:https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8675

```
$StoreName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My 
$StoreLocation = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser 
$Store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($StoreName, $StoreLocation) 
$Flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable 
$Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("/home/tech/scripts/powershell_scripts/exchangecert/msexchange.cer","apassword",$Flag) 
$Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite) 
$Store.Add($Certificate) 
$Store.Close() 

### FAILED RESULT
Connect-MgGraph: [Subject]
  CN=adomain.com
[Issuer]
  CN=adomain.com
[Serial Number]
  aserialnumber
[Not Before]
  5/30/2021 2:51:16 PM
[Not After]
  5/30/2022 3:01:17 PM
[Thumbprint]
  athumbprint
 certificate was not found or has expired.
```

Everything I have tried so far is failing. I know this would work on windows but I would really like to authenticate unattended on ubuntu.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-CertificateName` should be the subject name of the cert, not the path to the cert. But, you should probably try using the thumbprint instead. I think you're missing some more code for installing the cert. Try something like this, substituting your details in the beginning to generate the correct PFX. (i.e. Make sure key.pem and cert.pem exist in /etc/ssl/private/)

```
$CertPath = '/etc/ssl/private/'
$CertKey = $CertPath + 'key.pem'
$CertPublic = $CertPath + 'cert.pem'
$CertMerge = $CertPath + 'merged.pfx'
$CertPass = 'somepassword'
$CertExpire = 365
$CertName = 'somecertname')

# Generate new certificate and convert it to pfx format
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days $CertExpire -keyout $CertKey -out $CertPublic -subj "/C=LV/ST=Some-State/L=LV/O=$CertName/OU=IT"
openssl pkcs12 -in $CertPublic -inkey $CertKey -export -out $CertMerge -passout pass:$CertPass
```

At this point, you should check to make sure merged.pfx got created. Then continue:

```
# Store certificate in certificate store
$StoreName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My 
$StoreLocation = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser
$Store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($StoreName, $StoreLocation) 
$Flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($CertMerge, $CertPass, $Flag)
$Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$Store.Add($Certificate)
$Store.Close() 

# Get cert thumbprint
$CertValue = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetRawCertData())
$Thumbprint = $Certificate.Thumbprint
```

Then use `$Thumbprint` to log in:

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $ApplicationId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateThumbprint "YOUR_CERT_THUMBPRINT"
```

Comment: I actually tried to create a cert using that method and Azure didn't like the pem file. Is there a way I can get this a cer file instead? Other than that, I think this would have worked.

Comment: Actually I am going to mark yours as the answer. I wasn't able to use your cert but I was able to use most of your code for my cert that I already made and uploaded to azure. Now it says `Welcome To Microsoft Graph!` Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mentalnoob I think the first part maybe wasn't necessary because you already had the cert in your local store, but I'm glad the rest after that worked out!